# User permissions problem Linux

Tags: files, permissions, group

Every time I create a new file from "eclipse", I need to run these two lines of code to get the r/w permission:

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/folder/filename.extension
```

And/Or

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

And, If I copy some files over that server folder, and access it from browser URL like :

```
localhost/folder/filename.extension
```

I get a Permission error by Apache Server.

Isn't there any way so that I can get rid of this problem?

***Note:** The main error occurs when my `move_uploaded_file()` function tries to move the file to `/var/www/MyProject/` directory.

Answer (score 5):

**Use the SGID bit.**

Do this once, and forget about this problem:

```
chmod g+s /var/www/folder
```

You might want to do the same for all the sub-folders:

```
find /var/www/folder -type d | xargs chmod g+s
```

and, just in case:

```
find /var/www/folder -type d | xargs chgrp www-data
```

Now all the files that are created under `/var/www/folder/` will belong to the group that owns the containing folder, no matter what. This will allow you to create any files or folders without worrying that they will not belong to, for example, the *www-data* group, which is what you want.

*Please note, this will work only for files or folders that are created within the directory. If files are created elsewhere and moved into the directory tree, you still need to change ownership manually.*

**Example:**

```sh
# Create folder that belongs to www-data group
$ mkdir test
$ chown john.www-data test
$ ls -l

drwxr-xr-x 2 john www-data 4096 Jun 17 10:14 test

# Create a file, check the ownership
$ touch test/file1
$ ls -l test/

-rw-r--r-- 1 john users       0 Jun 17 10:16 file1

# Set the SGID bit
$ chmod g+s test
$ ls -l

drwxr-sr-x 2 john www-data 4096 Jun 17 10:19 test

# Create a file, check the ownership
$ touch test/file2
$ ls -l test/

-rw-r--r-- 1 john users       0 Jun 17 10:18 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 john www-data    0 Jun 17 10:19 file2
```

More info [here](http://www.switchroot.com/special-permissions-in-linux-suid-sgid-sticky-bit).

Comment: How does that command specify my desired user.??

Comment: As Andrejs said, the files will belong to the same group as the folder.

Comment: @ManishShrestha, you do not need to specify the user. You need to make sure that all files belongs to *www-data* group.

Comment: This works unless files are moved into the directory. SGID  will only enforce the group of the folder it's set on for files that are created within it. If this is a concern then ACLs is your next best bet.

Comment: @slm, true. I should mention that in my answer.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs still something is messy. How do i give permission to "www-data" to write file access inside "/var/www/MyProject" folder.

Comment: Obviously, `chown user:www-data /var/www/MyProject && chmod 775 /var/www/MyProject`.

Comment: You should specify your system's Linux distro! Also, make sure question is specific with *ALL* pertinent information, please! Are you trying to have a script create files within that directory? Do you have SELinux, apparmor, etc...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use default ACLs for assigning user and group permissions to new files and directories:

```
setfacl -dR u:domain:rwx,g:www-data:rwx /var/www/folder/filename.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to point out that should be more specific when asking questions; e.g. What OS, linux distribution are you using, as that can expedite the process of finding a solution greatly.  Having said that, you can start troubleshooting by changing the specific folder's **ownership** and **UAC** (User Access Control) recursively, like so:

```
chown domain:www-data /var/www/folder -chR

chmod 775 /var/www/folder -cR
```

**NOTE**:  By excluding the trailing slash **(/)** at the end of the folder's name, your changes will apply to the folder and all of its contents.

---

As for the permission-errors upon accessing the file (script?) in the browser, you have to make sure that your user has the correct permissions to serve files in `apache`.  That should be taken care of by editing your `/etc/httpd/*/httpd.conf` file and adding:

```
User domain
Group www-data
```

Comment: I dont have any `httpd` folder inside `/etc`

Comment: wherever your apache config file is:

`find /etc/ -iname 'httpd.conf'`

Comment: BTW: you *still* haven't said what Linux distribution you're using!